# How can I get a LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sorted by value from an unsorted Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, java-stream, linkedhashmap

I have a `Map<String, Integer>` mapping "words" to their number of occurrences in a larger original `String`.

I'm making a word cloud and I need to render the words with the greatest number of occurrences first to make sure they don't get truncated when there isn't enough room to render them after too many smaller words have been placed.

I tried doing something like:

```
public static WordCounter getSortedWordCounter(WordCounter wordCounter) {
    Map<String, Integer> sortedWordCountMap = wordCounter.getAll().entrySet().stream()
               .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
               .limit(10)
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

    return new WordCounter(sortedWordCountMap);
}
```

This gives me a `WordCounter` with the top 10 results but since `Collectors.toMap` is returning a regular `Map`, their order isn't sorted, it's random.

If I try storing the result of the `stream()` into a `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>` it tells me I can't use `Entry::getKey` or `Entry::getValue` in a static context because `Collectors.toMap()` is static.

Comment: Why not collect to a `List` of `Map.Entry`?  `Collectors.toList()` should do that.

Comment: I can't figure out the syntax for that. What goes inside `Collectors.toList(xxx)`?

Comment: You would replace `Collectors.toMap(...)` with just `Collectors.toList()`, I believe.  [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) does not take any arguments.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks! I'll see what I can do with that.